# Moving character in Unity3D based on accelerometer input

Tags: c#, performance, unity3d, mobile

I am building a infinite vertical platformer for mobile platforms using Unity3D. I am using the accelerometer to move the character left and right on the screen.

```
if (Input.acceleration.y > -0.2f && Input.acceleration.y < 0.2f) {
                        maxSpeed = 17;
                }

        if (Input.acceleration.y > -0.5f && Input.acceleration.y < -0.2f) {
            maxSpeed = 25;
        }
        if (Input.acceleration.y > 0.2f && Input.acceleration.y < 0.5f) {
            maxSpeed = 25;
        }
        if (Input.acceleration.y > -0.7f && Input.acceleration.y < -0.5f) {
            maxSpeed = 25;
        }
        if (Input.acceleration.y > 0.5f && Input.acceleration.y < 0.9f) {
            maxSpeed = 25;
        }
        if (Input.acceleration.y < -0.9f) {
            maxSpeed = 40;
        }
        if (Input.acceleration.y  > 0.9f) {
            maxSpeed = 40;
        }
```

Basically the farther the device is tilted the faster the character moves. I'm pretty sure there is a way better way to write this code but I'm pretty terrible at math and I can't figure it out. Any suggestions on cleaning this up a bit?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I know absolutely nothing about [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) or [unity3d](/questions/tagged/unity3d), so if there's a language specific assist, I have no idea about it!

I notice each condition checks `Input.acceleration.y`, so that's one bit of information that repeats. I also notice we have three speeds, yet we have seven conditionals!

First of all, the negatives are confusing. Find the absolute value first.

I'm going to assume a number followed by an "f" means float. So maybe we need something like:

```
float acceleration = Math.Abs(Input.acceleration.y);
```

Great, now it's going to be easier to handle this!

Now all we need is a simple check like so:

```
if (acceleration < 0.2f) {
    maxSpeed = 17;
} else if (acceleration < 0.9f) {
    maxSpeed = 25;
} else {
    maxSpeed = 40;
}
```

Your original numbers were a little weird, but if you meant for such a strange pattern, correct me!

Comment: This looks quite nice, but won't get the same result for e.g -0.2f

Comment: What do you mean? If the acceleration is -0.2f, then find the absolute value: 0.2f. Plug this in and you get a `maxSpeed` of 25. In the code, it actually omits -0.2f, which is what I meant by "strange pattern"!

Comment: `In your code, you actually omit -0.2f`-> not me but the OP

Comment: Sorry @Heslacher, I was thinking you were the OP replying! I've been up for a while ;)

Answer (score 7):

Here is your number line:

```
  …<-40->|      |<-25->|<--25-->|<-17->|<-17->|<--25-->|<----25----->|<-40->…
        -0.9  -0.7   -0.5     -0.2     0    +0.2     +0.5          +0.9
```

The first likely bug that I see is that the ranges are discontinuous.  For example, if `Input.acceleration.y` is *exactly* 0.5, then none of the cases applies.

Once you fix that bug, you can simplify the number line to the following equivalent:

```
  …<-40->|      |<------25----->|<-----17---->|<---------25--------->|<-40->…
       -0.9   -0.7            -0.2          +0.2                   +0.9
```

The next likely bug is that the two sides are asymmetrical, and there is a strange gap between -0.9 and -0.7.  Perhaps you meant to fill that in with `maxSpeed = 25`?  I'll assume you meant…

```
  …<-40->|<---------25--------->|<-----17---->|<---------25--------->|<-40->…
       -0.9                   -0.2          +0.2                   +0.9
```

Since the entire number line from -∞ to +∞ is covered, you should be able to avoid the double-ended inequality comparisons, and instead chain them with else-ifs.  Or, if you like more compact expressions, you could use ternary operators:

```
float absY = Input.acceleration.y < 0 ? -Input.acceleration.y : Input.acceleration.y;
maxSpeed = (absY < 0.2f) ? 17
         : (absY < 0.9f) ? 25
         :                 40;
```

The first line could also be written using [`Math.Abs()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2yzeea2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but I chose to write it this way to avoid converting the `float` to a `double`.

Answer (score 5):

You're missing some cases, for example what should happen when `y = 0.5`? Or `-0.9f < y < -0.7`?

I think this is valid representation of your current code:

```
y:   -inf    -0.9f  -0.7f  -0.5f   -0.2f    0.2f    0.5f    0.9f       +inf
m:        40   ?   ?  ?  25  ?   25  ?   17  ?   25  ?   25  ?    40
```

Based on this diagram, the code posted in @AlexL's answer is likely what you want to achieve. If you're trying to do something else, please post another question with more details :)

Answer (score 5):

**Also I favourite `Alex L`'s answer, her is an alternative way**

The first 5 `if conditions` are checking if the given `Input.acceleration.y` is **between** two float values.

So we can extract the `between` part to an extension method like

```
public static Boolean Between(this float num, float lower, float upper)
{
    return lower < num && num < upper;
}
```

we assign the value of `Input.acceleration.y` to a variable, first for readability and second this property only needs to be read only once.

```
float accelerationY = Input.acceleration.y;
```

next we are using the Between() method

```
    if (accelerationY.Between(-0.2f, 0.2f))
    {
        maxSpeed = 17;
    }
    else if (accelerationY.Between(-0.5f, -0.2f)
        || accelerationY.Between(0.2f, 0.5f)
        || accelerationY.Between(-0.7f, -0.5f)
        || accelerationY.Between(0.5f, 0.9f))
    {
        maxSpeed = 25;
    }
    else if (accelerationY < -0.9f || accelerationY>0.9f)
    {
        maxSpeed = 40;
    }
```

Comment: If you want to preserve the original behaviour (in a bug-compatible way), this is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Do you actually want the movement speed to be incremental? From the way you've phrased your question I get the impression that you actually want a linear gradient of movement speed with the tilt level of the device.

Here's an alternative option if this if what you actually want.

```
public class CharacterMover : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Declare the max speeds at which the player can move left and right
    private float maxLeftXAxisSpeed = -20f, maxRightXAxisSpeed = 20f;

    //Speed assigned for in-game movement
    private float moveXAxisSpeed = 0f;

    void Update()
    {
        //If the device is tilting
        if(Input.acceleration.y != 0)
        {
            moveXAxisSpeed = ConvertBetweenRanges(Input.acceleration.y, -1f, 1f, maxLeftXAxisSpeed, maxRightXAxisSpeed);
        }           

        //you would want to assign the transform of the gameobject to the moveXAxisSpeed here
    }

    //This is an extension method to convert between two ranges of float values
    private float ConvertBetweenRanges(float oldValue, float oldMin, float oldMax,
                                             float newMin, float newMax)
    {
        float newValue = (((oldValue - oldMin) * (newMax - newMin))/(oldMax - oldMin) + newMin);
        return newValue;
    }
}
```

I would suggest making the ConvertBetweenRanges method an extension method of the float class so that you can call it from anywhere. How to do that is a different question!